# Clarification about Direct Proofs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I was wondering what exactly constitutes a direct proof in discrete mathematics.

For example if I prove an equation for some number larger than $n$, with a formula given to be used such as Euler's Formula, would this still be considered a direct proof as it is not induction or contradiction, etc?

Thanks

Comment: Well, you could check the wikipedia definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_proof

Comment: I think of induction as a direct proof, provided you don't use any indirect methods within the proof itself.